# Tracking Gantt Chart Not Showing All Tasks

Tags: ms-project, gantt

I am trying to do an earned value analysis and there are tasks in my normal Gantt chart that when I switch the view to tracking gantt are not visible. Could this have to do  with where I set my status date? I set the status date to a point where all of the work in the project should be completed but I dont know if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the Tracking Gantt view has been inadvertently modified to incorporate a task filter - either a named filter or an autofilter on a particular column. (The latter can be particularly hard to spot if the filtered column is not visible.)

To correct the issue.... On the Filter pull-down menu (in the Data group of the View ribbon/tab), select Clear Filter.